# Add a button after loading TinyMCE via JQuery and it's not working

Tags: jquery, tinymce

I'm loading TinyMCE via JQuery and after it's loaded, I'd like to add a save button to it. The save button is calling a function but Firebug says the function is not defined, in this case destroyTinyMCE() is not defined. What's wrong?

```
$('div#introText').click(function() {
        loadTinyMCE();
        $('div#introText').after('<input value="Save" onclick="destroyTinyMCE();" type="button">');
});

function loadTinyMCE() {
//some variable
}

function destroyTinyMCE() {
       $('div#introText').tinymce().destroy();
       $('div#introText').tinymce().remove();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is inside your `document.ready` handler, then that `destroyTinyMCE` function is scoped only to it, and when looking for it in the global namespace (as `onclick="destroyTinyMCE();"` will do), it won't be there.  Instead attach the click handler when creating it, like this:

```
$('<input value="Save" type="button">').click(destroyTinyMCE)
                                       .insertAfter('div#introText');
```

This will reference the function correctly and it can still be tucked away inside whatever closure you're in currently.

Comment: Oh thanks! It looks good but I got 'e.selection is null' in Firebug :(

Comment: @everisk - Sounds like something inside tinymce, which version are you on?

Comment: I switch to another editor and it's now working. Thanks a alot!